# Can I prevent my iPhone from adding an odd character when dictating messages in the third party app GroupMe?

Tags: iphone, ios, windows, android, voice-dictation

Whenever I send a message on GroupMe from my iPhone and I use dictation, I always find this character at the end of my message when I open it on a Windows or on my Android: `￼`.  It only shows up on non-apple devices, so in case you're on one and it doesn't show up:

[image: OBJ] [image]

I don't know what it means, or [what is this object translation character used for](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EF%BF%BC).

I've tried pressing the end dictation button after I'm done speaking yet it gets sent nonetheless.

Can I filter or stop this behavior?

Comment: So you don't see it on any Apple device?  See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%EF%BF%BC

Comment: Yes @TomGewecke - I wonder what would happen if people dictate emoji or other styled text and see how that gets converted by this app before it sends the message...